# Exam gradetable with bonus column

Tags: exam, gradetable

We want to add bonus questions to our exams but not as a separate section but instead of a question number. Is this possible without manipulating the exam package?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question [1] Question 1
    \question [2] Question 2
    \bonusquestion [2] What's your favorite color?
\end{questions}

\gradetable[h]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam} 


%******************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\chbpword{Bonus Question:}  
\gdef\bonuspoint@block{Bonus Question:}%

\xapptocmd{\questions}{%
    \def\bonusquestion{%
                \@bonustrue%
                \def\thequestiontitle{Bonus}%
                \process@question%
            }%
            }{}{}
\makeatother
%******************************************** 

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question [10] Question 1
        \question [20] Question 2
        \bonusquestion [35] What's your favorite color?
    \end{questions} 

    \combinedpointtable[h][questions] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\end{document}
```

With    `\combinedgradetable[h][questions]`

[image: c]

**UPDATE** after follow up question

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}     

%******************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\chbpword{Bonus Question:}  
\gdef\bonuspoint@block{Bonus Question:}%

\xapptocmd{\questions}{%
    \def\bonusquestion{%
                \@bonustrue%
                \def\thequestiontitle{Bonus}%
                \process@question%
            }%
            }{}{}
        
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\if@bonus\relax\else\thequestion.\fi}
\makeatother
%******************************************** 
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question [10] Question 1
        \question [20] Question 2
        \bonusquestion [35] What's your favorite color? 
    \end{questions} 

    \combinedgradetable[h][questions] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Could it be just "Bonus Question:" without "3. "? Where do I find documentation to this @block statement?

Comment: @RootRaven (1) Please see the updated answer. (2) You have to scan the `exam.cls` with a text editor and see the comments. Look around line 3977.